# Summarizing a dynamic array after merging with another table in KQL

Tags: sql, kql

This is something I'm trying to figure out within KQL - in this example it is calculating the total cost of the order for each customer.

**Customer**

| Name | Order |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | [1, 2, 3] |
| Kate | [1, 3] |

**Items**

| ID | Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 1.00 |
| 2 | Orange | 1.50 |
| 3 | Banana | 1.75 |

All I have got so far is that if I want to calculate the cost of Bob's order I might do something like

```
let order = Customer
| where Name == "Bob"
| project Order;
Items
| where ID in (order)
| summarize total_cost = sum(Price)
```

However if I wanted to do this for Bob **and** Kate, and any number of other "customers" I have no idea of how to get to this end goal.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Even though this is in KQL specifically, even knowing how to do it in SQL would allow me to hopefully translate it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

- start with `mv-expand`ing the array of orders.
- continue with a `lookup` of the `Price` in the `Items` table.
- finish with a `summarize` of the `sum()` of `Price` by `Name`.

```
let Customer = datatable(Name:string, Order:dynamic) [
    'Bob', dynamic([1, 2, 3]),
    'Kate', dynamic([1, 3]),
]
;
let Items = datatable(ID:long, Name:string, Price:double) [
    1, 'Apple', 1.00,
    2, 'Orange', 1.50,
    3, 'Banana', 1.75,
]
;
Customer
| mv-expand Order to typeof(long)
| lookup Items on $left.Order == $right.ID
| summarize sum(Price) by Name
```

| Name | sum_Price |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 4.25 |
| Kate | 2.75 |